# Spring BOOT resources

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have a maven project with spring boot, the project is packaged in a jar file. I want to access the txt file or xml file int the folder `src/main/resources/`. How can I achieve this? I've tried code like this: `URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("...");`, but it does not work for me.
I have added the resources in the pom.xml file :

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.bin</include>
                <include>**/*.tagger</include>
                <include>**/*.txt</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any resources configuration in `pom.xml`, I am doing it in this way.

```
URL url =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file_name_goes_here.txt");

String fileContent = IOUtils.toString(url);
```

Note that I have used `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` for getting the file contents.

This is what I have in `<build>`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```